# visual studio 2013 debug mode and console don't working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I used visual studio 2013 two days ago. 
But now... It does not working. 
I tested below c code and cpp code.

```
    //#include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    void main(){
       //printf("hi");
       //cout << "test" << endl;
       int a;
       cin >> a;
       cout << a;
    }
```

The result of run is just blinking console. 
And does not appear "Press Enter..." 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qSVw.png)

If I try to debug then Visual studio stop and no response.

I do reset all options :(

Comment: Did you try typing a number and hitting enter?

Answer (score 0):

Your console is showing the output but not waiting for you to see it.
you need to add break point or for workaround you can use

```
  cout << a;
  int ch = std::cin.get();
}
```

you must be able to see the value of a.

EDIT: ohh you would need fflush too, my fault too miss it.

```
  cout << a;
  fflush(stdin);
  int ch = std::cin.get();
}
```